# PHPUNIT weird error

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit

In my application I have this weird error **when testing only**, I am not testing any classes in my Repo folder yet but have this:

```
Call to undefined method Application_Model_Cache::getInstance() in C:\wamp\www\truCrowd_dev\application\models\Repo\User.php on line 12
```

My user Repo is:

```
class Application_Model_Repo_User
{
    private $_database;
    private $_cache   ;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->_database   = Application_Model_Database::getInstance();
        $this->_cache      = Application_Model_Cache::getInstance();
        $this->_longCache  = Application_Model_Cache::getInstance(604800);
    }
```

My cache class is:

```
class Application_Model_Cache
{
    public static function getInstance($_expiration = 7200)
    {  
        $frontend= array(
        'lifetime' => $_expiration,
        'automatic_serialization' => true
        );

        $backend= array(
        'cache_dir' => './cache/',
        );

        $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Output',
            'File',
            $frontend,
            $backend
        );
        return $cache;
    }
}
```

My testing bootstrap is:

```
<?php

// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV') || define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'production');

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

I Have tried to change the Cache class by having to instantiate it but I get the same result...
My Database class has the exact structure but I haven`t gotten this in the past, now that I advanced in development I wanted to make tests and the error appeared

Comment: Are you mocking the Application_Model_Cache class in any of your tests? depending on the way you're doing that, maybe the mock is being used as a unique instance so the method does not exist. Also, have you tried to isolate the test that makes the error happen?

Comment: If I am testing the Cache class? Could you explain a bit please? Zend_Cache doesn`t seem (at least to me) to have a singleton implementationso multiple instances can be made...

Comment: Hacked it by dissabling the cache in my config but still... :|

Comment: OK, Note to self: Never program at 3 AM else make sure when writing test scripts to append 'Test' in the class name because it will be overwritten...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether Application_Model_Cache class is being mocked in any of your tests, and if the mock is not being used when calling the non existent method.